# window.location.href not working on Windows Phone 7.1/7.5

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1, window.location

Basically I'm doing a simple JS redirect when an event is fired, this code works on a whole host of other mobile/desktop browsers (including desktop versions of IE), but not on WP7.1 and WP7.5 (I don't have any other WP devices to test on).

```
window.location.href = "/item_details/" + item_id;
```

The behavior I'm seeing is the URL is replaced inside the navigation bar on the phone and it acts like it's loading the page; the progress bar slowly increases up until ~90% when it hangs indefinitely.  Looking at the logs on my server I see NO incoming connections from the device.  If I click in the address bar and and submit it manually the intended page immediately loads.

I see the same behavior with each of the following lines too:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"
window.location.replace = "http://www.google.com"
window.location = "http://www.google.com"
```

In every case the loading bar progresses to ~90% and stops, not making any outgoing connections.

Comment: Two questions: Is this call from within an `iframe`, and is the call inside of any sort of Ajax post method?

Comment: @couzzi Not in an iframe nor Ajax call, it's the only line in a function called from an onclick on an anchor tag.

Comment: Wait, why are you wrapping logic around the `onclick` of an anchor tag? Is allowing the anchor to be clicked naturally (without any Javascript interference) an option: `<a href="http://google.com">Click</a>`

Comment: window.location.replace is a function.. so you should try window.location.replace("url");

Comment: @couzzi  Ha, it does look a little strange.  Basically I'm using the same template and selectively loading in some JS for mobile vs desktop browsers.  On the desktop version that function opens up a modal dialog, on mobile it just redirects.

Comment: Gotcha. Can you post that bit of code?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the issue was having `href="javascript:void(0)"` in the anchor tag was causing the issue with mobile IE.  Removing that caused the redirect to work flawlessly!

Comment: Nice to a see a reason to ditch the whole void(0) technique. I hate seeing that in markup.

Comment: Darn. I was searching for an answer to this same problem, using a window.location = "http:// ... " redirect in the onload event of a page body tag. Like you, I found it worked on every browser to a reasonable version history, until a friend with a windows phone (version WP8 he says) tested and found your same behavior... loading display but page never changes. Sadly in my case, I have no anchor tag with a javascript:void(0) to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach and see if the problem is isolated/related to `window.location`.

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = "http://www.google.com";
document.body.appendChild(anchor);
anchor.click();
```

Comment: No luck, seeing the same behavior as with `window.location`